# Optimisation of a function of many binary variables.

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a function defined over a large $N$-dimensional space
$$f\left(\frac{\mathbf{b}}{|\mathbf{b}|}\right)$$
with $b_i\in \{0,1\}$, $|\mathbf{b}|=\sum_{i=1}^Nb_i$. The goal is to find the minimum of $f$. For $N=2$ the question would amount to figure which of the inputs $(0,1), (1,0), (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ minimises $f$. When $N$ is sufficiently large it becomes impossible to numerically explore all the space.

One approach could be to start from the homogeneous initial state $b_i=1/N$, and perform a *greed search* by removing one element from the vector $\mathbf{b}$ at a time.

- Is there a standard approach to treat this sort of optimisation problems?
- Alternatively, any suggestions for a better algorithm than the greed search mentioned above?

Comment: what happens if all $b_i$s are $0$?

Comment: right. That case should not be considered. One should always have $\sum_i b_i/|\mathbf{b}| = 1$.

Comment: What is the function $f$ you want to minimize?

Comment: I don't know much about it's form, it is estimated through a model. I just know it's not necessarily convex.

Comment: Search term: “black-box optimization”